# LibGDX Button not responding on touch

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

My first problem is that the textfield is not showing up and the second is that the button is not responding. My idea is when image 'vault1' is touched the textfield should show 5.

This is what I have come up with and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

(I have only cut out neseccary code)

```
public void render(float delta) {

    drawSprite("vault1", 600, 450);
}

public void show() {

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/menuSkin.json"), new TextureAtlas("ui/atlas.pack"));

    vaultInput = new TextField("", skin);
    vaultInput.setPosition(300, 250);
    vaultInput.setSize(300, 40);
    vaultInput.setText(text2);
    vault1Button = new Image(vault1);

    vault1Button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int point, int button) {
            System.out.println("133");
           vaultInput.setText(score);
            return false;
        }});
}

private void drawSprite(String name, float x, float y) {
    Sprite sprite = textureAtlas.createSprite(name);

    sprite.setPosition(x, y);

    sprite.draw(batch);
    vault1 = sprite;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell when you've left out code but you are adding the stage to the input processor:

```
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

The stage and actors added to the stage is now the only things that responds to input. But you are never adding anything to the stage and neither drawing the stage, you are drawing your sprites seperately in the drawSprite method.

If you instead add your button to the stage all you need to do is call stage.draw():

```
public void render(float delta) {
    stage.draw();
    stage.act(delta);
}

public void show() {
   Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
       skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/menuSkin.json"), new TextureAtlas("ui/atlas.pack"));


    vaultInput = new TextField("", skin);
    vaultInput.setPosition(300, 250);
    vaultInput.setSize(300, 40);
    vaultInput.setText(text2);
    vault1Button = new Image(vault1);


    vault1Button = new Image(vault1);



    vault1Button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int point, int button) {
            System.out.println("133");
           vaultInput.setText(score);
            return false;
    }});
    vaultInput.setPosition(x1, y1);
    vault1Button.setPosition(x2, y2);
    stage.addActor(vaultInput);
    stage.addActor(vault1Button);
}
```

Everything added to the stage will be drawn when calling stage.draw()

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `vault1` field is still null when `show()` is called. So your actual button that you added your listener to has zero size and nothing to draw.

Also, since `render()` is called continuously in the game loop, you are creating new sprites to draw on every frame and reassigning the `vault1` variable every frame.

You need to create your image for the button in `show()` and add the button to the stage. Then you only need to draw the stage.